# Rosbagging MoveIt! Best practise

Tags: moveit, rosbag, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody

Every once in a while I see some strange movements executed by our robots (mitsubishi, fanuc, ... - industrial 6-axis). Since execution has continued already it's of course difficult to debug this. I would like to be able to record both what I *told* the robot to do and what it then *did*.

I think rosbagging /joint_path_command and /joint states should do the trick. How do I play back those? I would like to see them visualized in rviz

Does anybody do this? Got some code to share?

Thanks a lot

Simon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247377/rosbagging-moveit!-best-practise/) by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2016-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Simon,

I have done something similar before and I used a publisher with type `moveit_msgs::DisplayRobotState` (easily visualized using the rviz RobotState plugin). It should be pretty easy to load the bag file and step through the relevant states, visualizing both the `/joint_states` and `/joint_path_command` states. Unfortunately I can't share any code on that at the moment.

Another, perhaps easier option would be to use [moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools).

Good luck

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0